# How to add a clickable font-icon (like FontAwseome) to a Html.Grid?

Tags: razor, razor-grid

I could not find the answer anywhere, but i ended up with a solution described below.

If anyone knows a 'better' way...

Answer (score 0):

Note the double quotes in the html string!

```
.Columns(column => {
    column.For(m => 
        Html.Raw(
            string.Format(
                @"<a href=""{0}""><i class=""fa fa-pencil-square""></i></a>", 
                Url.Action("EditItem","MyController", new { id = m.id })
            )
        )
    );
 })
```